# How to change "self.view.layoutMargins". it stay (0, 16, 0, 16)

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I want to change the margins between 'self.view' and 'subView' to UIEdgeInsetsZero, but it stay (0, 16, 0, 16).
How could I solve this problem, and why it is (0, 16, 0, 16) instead of (8, 8, 8, 8)?

[redView's margins stay (0, 16, 0, 16)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Lb3.png)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    UIView * subView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:subView];
    subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSArray * H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[subView]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading metrics:nil views:@{@"subView": subView}];

    NSArray * V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[subView]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing metrics:nil views:@{@"subView": subView}];

    [self.view addConstraints:H];
    [self.view addConstraints:V];
}
```

Comment: do you get any constraint error output when you run your code? do you have any constraints setup in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622566-layoutmargins):

> If the view is a view controller’s root view, the system sets and manages the margins. The top and bottom margins are set to zero points. The side margins vary depending on the current size class, but can be either 16 or 20 points. You cannot change these margins.

Hence, if you want the padding between self.view and subView to be `(8, 8, 8, 8)`, you need to have visual formats as `@"H:|-8-[subView]-8-|"` and `@"V:|-8-[subView]-8-|"` for horizontal and vertical constraints respectively.